# Changing schema using a stored procedure with FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENT

Tags: sql-server, xml, xsd, sql-server-2008-r2

Right now I'm getting schema in XML format like this

```
<Header>
  <data1> </data1>
  <Line>
      <data> </data>
      <VLine>
            <data> </data>
            <LUI></LUI>
      </Vline>
  </Line>
</Header>
```

By using following stored procedure

```
Select * from
EDI834_5010_Header Header
join EDI834_5010_2000 Line on Header.BGN02__TransactionSetIdentifierCode = Line.Id_BGN02__TransactionSetIdentifierCode
left join EDI834_5010_2300_DTPLoop VLine on Line.REF02_MemberSupplementalIdentifier = VLine.Id_REF02__SubscriberIdentifier and Header.BGN02__TransactionSetIdentifierCode = VLine.Id_BGN02__TransactionSetIdentifierCode
left join EDI834_5010_2300_LUILoop LUI on LUI.Id_BGN02__TransactionSetIdentifierCode=Header.BGN02__TransactionSetIdentifierCode and LUI.Id_REF02__SubscriberIdentifier=Line.REF02_MemberSupplementalIdentifier
for xml auto,ELEMENTS

END
```

But I need to get the schema like this in xml

```
<Header>
    <data1> </data1>
    <Line>
       <data> </data>
       <VLine>
          <data> </data>
       </Vline>
       <LUI>
             <data> </data>
       </LUI> 
    </Line>
</Header>
```

How should I change my above stored procedure to get the schema like this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, not tested by me so there may be any number of typos in there.

```
select *,
       (select *
        from EDI834_5010_2300_DTPLoop VLine
        where Line.REF02_MemberSupplementalIdentifier = VLine.Id_REF02__SubscriberIdentifier and Header.BGN02__TransactionSetIdentifierCode = VLine.Id_BGN02__TransactionSetIdentifierCode
        for xml auto, elements, type),
       (select *
        from EDI834_5010_2300_LUILoop LUI
        where LUI.Id_BGN02__TransactionSetIdentifierCode=Header.BGN02__TransactionSetIdentifierCode and LUI.Id_REF02__SubscriberIdentifier=Line.REF02_MemberSupplementalIdentifier 
        for xml auto, elements, type)
from EDI834_5010_Header Header
  join EDI834_5010_2000 Line 
    on Header.BGN02__TransactionSetIdentifierCode = Line.Id_BGN02__TransactionSetIdentifierCode
for xml auto, elements
```

Used this to test if the sub-queries work and it looks like they do.

```
declare @t1 table (id int)
declare @t2 table (id int)
declare @t3 table (id int)

insert into @t1 values (1),(2)
insert into @t2 values (1),(2)
insert into @t3 values (1),(2)

select *,
       (select *
        from @t2 as t2
        where t1.id = t2.id
        for xml auto, elements, type),
       (select *
        from @t3 as t3
        where t1.id = t3.id
        for xml auto, elements, type)
from @t1 as t1
for xml auto, elements
```

Result:

```
<t1>
  <id>1</id>
  <t2>
    <id>1</id>
  </t2>
  <t3>
    <id>1</id>
  </t3>
</t1>
<t1>
  <id>2</id>
  <t2>
    <id>2</id>
  </t2>
  <t3>
    <id>2</id>
  </t3>
</t1>
```

Comment: Thanks Mikael Eriksson. This solved my problem. This query is giving xml in correct format...

Comment: @saurabhmohan Good to hear. Then you should consider accepting this answer. Have a look here how it works. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work